# TypeError: sort_values() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

what will be the solution to above problem?

```
Given a dataframe, you have to sort the rows based on values of one column.
Note: Sorting should be in descending order of values of given column
The input will contain a column name. The output should contain the first five rows of the dataframe.
The output will contain the first n rows of the sorted dataframe.
Sample Input:
TOEFL Score
Sample Output:

     Serial No.  GRE Score  TOEFL Score  University Rating  SOP  LOR   CGPA  \
25           26        340          120                  5  4.5   4.5  9.60   
97           98        331          120                  3  4.0   4.0  8.96   
81           82        340          120                  4  5.0   5.0  9.50   
202         203        340          120                  5  4.5   4.5  9.91   
203         204        334          120                  5  4.0   5.0  9.87   

     Research  Chance of Admit   
25          1              0.94  
97          1              0.86  
81          1              0.96  
202         1              0.97  
203         1              0.97  
Execution Time Limit
```

```
import pandas as pd 
col=input()
df=pd.read_csv("https://media-doselect.s3.amazonaws.com/generic/RM8r5NBrJdA4QeVZXvwbjokwv/Admission_Predict.csv")
#write your code here
sort = pd.DataFrame.sort_values(by="col", axis=0, ascending=False)
print(sort)
```

Comment: You need to pass ```df``` to ```sort_values``` not ```pd.DataFrame```

Comment: You are passing the string 'col' as a parameter not the variable. You should remove the quotes like this: sort = pd.DataFrame.sort_values(by= col, axis=0, ascending=False)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `sort = pd.DataFrame.sort_values(by="col", axis=0, ascending=False)` should be `sort = df.sort_values(by="col", axis=0, ascending=False)`. `pd.DataFrame` is making an new empty data frame that you are then trying to sort where sort expects to be called on a data frame with data already stored in it. df is the data frame with the data in it, not pd.

Answer (score 0):

correct code is

```
import pandas as pd 
col=input()
df=pd.read_csv("https://media-doselect.s3.amazonaws.com/generic/RM8r5NBrJdA4QeVZXvwbjokwv/Admission_Predict.csv")
print(df.sort_values(by=[col],ascending=False).head())
```